# Node.js ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'bluebird'

Tags: node.js, hexo

When I try this,it throw an error,how can I solve it?

```
$ hexo generate
ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'bluebird'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lihz/blog/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/lib/index.js:73:18
    at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:489:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:565:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:681:14)
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/lib/index.js:82:22
    at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:489:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:565:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

Answer (score 17):

You might  need to install the bluebird package locally. Try

```
npm install --save bluebird
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Bluebird folder was called 'bluebird' and i was importing it as 'Bluebird' (with a capital 'B') so i changed the import string to be 'bluebird' (im working on linux).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use registry to install modules. But I forgot that while downloading hexo-cli. when I run hexo, it responses me 'cannot find bluebird', even though it has been installed.

my solution is:

use registry to install hexo-cli again.

then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error came up when I had installed bluebird in the wrong directory.

When I downloaded Bluebird from my home directory

`myuser@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo npm install --save bluebird`

it is installed in `~/node_modules` (and I got some warnings by doing so), and I had to include it by using

```
var Promise = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/bluebird');
```

When I install Bluebird from the /usr/lib directory using

`myuser@raspberrypi:/usr/lib $ sudo npm install --save bluebird`

(no warnings), it is installed in `/usr/lib/node_modules` (next to the existing `npm` directory), and I had to include it by using

```
var Promise = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/bluebird');
```

So make sure you are aware of where the module is installed and that you refer to it accordingly. In general, [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) is a description where `require` looks for modules in nodejs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue. It looks as though `bluebird` is not downloading with its' `index.js` which would exposes all the functions as a module.

If you `cd` into `node_modules/bluebird` you may see that it does exist, but there is no `index.js`. Since there's no `index.js` node does not know how to require `bluebird`.

---

Here are a few items to try:

1. If you have a "proxying" npm registry, put a namespace on all packages you pull from that repository, and then edit your npm config pull all packages from the public NPM, unless they are namespaced to pull from your private NPM registry. You can see an example below of how to scope configuration to scopes.

   ```
   registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
   @dog:registry=https://npm.dog.com/
   @dog:always-auth=true
   //npm.dog.com/:_authToken="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
   @dog:cafile=/Users/dogboy/.ssh/dogtown.crt
   ```
2. Upgrade NPM versions.

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this?

Comment: Did you fix this?